# ¿Cómo puedo relacionar dos veces una tabla de diferente manera?

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo una duda en cuanto al diseño de una base de datos de ventas de juguetes, en donde ocupo que en un "ticket" de venta aparezcan tanto el cajero como el vendedor que realizaron la venta. Tanto el cajero como el vendedor se encuentran en la tabla "trabajadores" pero, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que pueda referenciar dos veces la misma tabla en diferentes conceptos?

[image: Aquí está la imagen del diseño que he hecho hasta ahora]

Comment: *"En diferentes conceptos"* ¿Cuáles conceptos? ¿Cómo se relacionan con una venta?

Comment: A "*vendedor"* te refieres al proveedor de ese producto? Si es así un proveedor es un agente externo, por qué estaría en trabajadores?

Comment: No, con vendedor me refiero al trabajador que le vende el producto al cliente

Comment: Con dos conceptos me refiero a que un trabajador tiene el concepto de vendedor, mientras que otro va a tener el de cajero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes agregar dos campos de referencia en la tabla ventas, una vez por cada *rol* que juega cada `trabajador`.  Es decir, una vez como cajero, otra vez como vendedor.

Por ejemplo:

```
create table venta (
    idVenta                   int not null primary key
  , Fecha                     date
  , monto                     date
  , idTrabajadorCajero        int
  , idTrabajadorVendedor      int
  , constraint FK_venta_TrabajadorCajero
      foreign key (idTrabajadorCajero)
      references Trabajador (idTrabajador)
  , constraint FK_venta_TrabajadorVendedor
      foreign key (idTrabajadorVendedor)
      references Trabajador (idTrabajador)
)
```

De esta forma tienes dos llaves foráneas entre la tabla `venta` y la tabla `trabajador`, una para el rol de cajero y otra para el rol de vendedor.

Puedes incluso abreviar los nombres de los campos solo a `idCajero` e `idVendedor`, aunque yo prefiero poder *observar* desde el nombre del campo la tabla con la que está relacionado, ya es una cuestión más de gustos que otra cosa.

OJO: Toma la sentencia como ejemplo, si entiendes el concepto, puedes aplicarlo a tu propia estructura, y puedes lograr las mismas relacionas modificando la estructura que ya tienes.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por ayudarme de nuevo, eso que hiciste ahí lo hice en el diseño físico de la base, pero. ¿Cómo puedo representarlo en el diagrama?

Comment: Igual, pones dos relaciones, una venta "es realizada" por el vendedor, y digamos que "es cobrada" o "es procesada" por el cajero. La entidad Venta debe reflejar los dos campos de relación.

Comment: Si intenté, pero no agrega dos campos, se queda con uno solo, déjame mostrarte
https://i.gyazo.com/d927023a96700591c0625380caabfedd.png

Comment: Ay no, qué pena, ya lo agregué

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue de mucha ayuda tu Respuesta